# Java if-else comparison

Tags: java

I've a program test to see if the user input is a positive number and an integer. The `if` statement test if it is an integer, the `else if` test if it is negative. If it is a negative or a decimals, the user is asked to input a positive integer. The problem is at the else statement, it is waiting for the user input again, I want it to use the value from `System.out.print("Enter the test number: ");` if it pass the if and else if test.

I try assigning the user input after `System.out.println("Please enter an integer!");`  to an int variable but if the user input a double, I would get an error so I figured this way didn't work. Any insight on how to make the program work is appreciated, thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class FibonacciNumbersTester  
{  
    public static void main(String[]args)  
    {   //Variables  
        Scanner userDed = new Scanner(System.in);  
        String userChoice = "Y";  
        while(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))  
        {  
            Scanner userNum = new Scanner(System.in);  
            System.out.print("Enter the test number: ");  
            if(!userNum.hasNextInt() )  
            {  
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer!");  
            }  
            else if(userNum.nextInt() < 0 )  
            {     
                System.out.println("Please enter a postive integer!");  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                int NumTo = userNum.nextInt();  
                System.out.println(NumTo);  
            }  

            System.out.print("Would you like to continue? (Y/N)");  
            userChoice = userDed.next();                
        }  
    }  
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Assign userNum.nextInt() to variable like int x = userNum.nextInt() And use x in both else if(x < 0) and else .

Comment: Would I assign it to a variable before the if statement? If yes, won't this give me an error if the user input in a double? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call [nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) once, save the result and use it for comparison.

Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) { // Variables
        Scanner userDed = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userChoice = "Y";
        while (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            Scanner userNum = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the test number: ");
            if (!userNum.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer!");
            } else {
                int NumTo = userNum.nextInt();
                if (NumTo < 0)
                    System.out.println("Please enter a postive integer!");
                else
                    System.out.println(NumTo);

            }
            System.out.print("Would you like to continue? (Y/N)");
            userChoice = userDed.next();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Iswanto, thanks you so much! Can't believe I haven't thought of this! Been changing my program for the past 8 hours and here you are saving my life. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern positiveInt = Pattern.compile("^[1-9]\d*$"); // for positive integer
if(!userNum.hasNext(positiveInt)) {
    System.out.println("Please enter an positive integer (greater than 0) !");  
}
else {
    int NumTo = userNum.nextInt(positiveInt);
    System.out.println(NumTo);  
}
```